# OpenType features 'case' not working in IE/Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, webfonts, opentype

I have texts in German on a website and headlines are always uppercase. So when there is for example "Straße" in the headline, there is a problem with the uppercase ß.
The webfont I got has the OpenType feature „Case Sensitive Form“ which makes ß to SS.
This works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not in IE or Edge.
I tried to manually set `font-feature-settings: 'case' on;` but this didn't change anything.

Does Edge not support this feature? 
Edge loads the WOFF2 file, just as Chrome, so it's not an error in the webfont, is it?

Comment: [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh869409(v=vs.94)) seems to list it at least for IE10, however they use `1` instead of `on` in the examples. Might or might not be the reason, but at least it should be supported.

Comment: Off topic, but I've always found it strange seeing words like STRASSE just because they have uppercase letters. Is STRAẞE really incorrect?

Comment: @MrLister officially the uppercase ß only exists since 2016, many fonts don't have the glyph. Using SS instead is still correct. And it just looks very unfamiliar/strange.

Comment: @Roope thanks for the information. So do you think it's an error with the font file?

Comment: @obs I tried various font files, but the result is always the same: Edge and IE display a ẞ while other browsers display SS. Unless all fonts have the same error, but I doubt that.

Comment: @MrLister thanks for testing that for me! It's not such a big thing, but I will try to find out what's going on here.

Comment: Can you please show the actual code you're using that works in FF/Chrome/Safari but not in Edge?

Comment: I don't need to do anything for this to work in FF/Chrome/Safari. I just use @font-face with WOFF2 and WOFF.

Comment: In that case it should be really simple for you to add a [mcve] as a snippet, which would help people who might want to help you, or even work on Edge.